# How to use dynamic data in Chart.Js with Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, dynamic, mongoose, handlebars.js

I'm trying to show dynamic data in Chart.Js using Node.js, mongoose, and Handlebars, also I have installed chartjs-node. The problem is that I don't know how to do that.

```
var schema = new Schema({
    author: String,
    post: String,
    choice: String
}, {
    timestamps: true
});
```

Functional example of Chart.js (public/javascripts/style.js)

```
new Chart($("#answerChart"), {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
      labels: ["Africa", "Asia", "Europe", "Latin America", "North America"],
      datasets: [{
        label: "Population (millions)",
        backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2","#3cba9f","#e8c3b9","#c45850"],
        data: [2478,5267,734,784,433]
      }]
    },
    options: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Predicted world population (millions) in 2050'
      }
    }
});
```

I need to show chart in an Handlebars file

Comment: well Mr/Ms Penguin, please do show your full code so that I can assist you.

Comment: I make some modification

Comment: I have done similar using sockets and highcharts before. Are you planning on the data changing and updating constantly, live in the chart? If so, you will need to use socket.io I believe, and then add an event to your chart that loads the data each update. The datasets[0].data would need to be set to the data sent from the socket emit event. The socket emit event would be emitted every time the db is updated. To sum up, there are a lot of parts missing from your code, so please update and ask more specific questions that you get stuck on.

Comment: I don't know if it's a good idea, but I put charts script into hbs file, and I can use something like .. text: '{{ title }}'